# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCellContentView' (0x111d61280) to 'UIImageView' (0x111d4cdd0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imageview, tableview

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to build YouTube Video App. 
I've got this error below.

> [14835:1757198] Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCellContentView' (0x111d61280) to 'UIImageView' (0x111d4cdd0).

And my code is below.

```
import UIKit

class tableview_blackpink: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var videos:[Video] = [Video]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let model = VideoModel()
    self.videos = model.getVideos()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return videos.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell")!
        //let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row].videoTitle

    //Customize the cell to display the video

        //cell.textLabel?.text = videoTitle

    //Construct the video thumbnail url
    let videoThumbnailUrlString = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/" + videos[indexPath.row].videoId + "/mqdefault.jpg"

    //Create NSURL object
    let videoThumbnailUrl = URL(string: videoThumbnailUrlString)

    if videoThumbnailUrl != nil{

        //Create NSURL request object
        let request = URLRequest(url: videoThumbnailUrl!)

        //Create NSURLSession

        let session = URLSession.shared
        //Create datatask and pass in the request
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in


                DispatchQueue.main.async{ 

                    //Get a reference to the imageView element of the cell
                    let imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

                    //Create an image object from the data and assign it into the imageView
                    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
        })

        dataTask.resume()

        }

        return cell
   }
}
```

And I got error here.

```
let imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

I've googled considerable amount and the answer I got was fix this

```
let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

to

```
let imageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

I tried this but still got same error. 
I'm following [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYIM0.jpg) YouTube video tutorial and code below doesn't work for latest Version.

[Code for Swift2.2 is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYIM0.jpg)
I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you adding a tag to the view?  It looks like you tagged the wrong one.

Comment: if you correctly assigned the tag for the imageView , then it should work akso it's better to create outlets instead of that messy way

Comment: @Sh_Khan I tried to connect imageView but I got "The imageView outlet from the tableview_blackpink to the UImageView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

Comment: can you screenshot the cell xib or prototype with tag

Comment: are you sure you've given tag `1` to the UIImageView?

Comment: Horrible tutorial. Rather than using outdated `viewWithTag` create a custom cell class with an outlet and loading asynchronous data in `cellForRow` without caching the image is a no-go. Imagine that the image is loaded again and again when the user scrolls. This is unnecessarily inefficient and expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imageView will be nil if it can't find a (tag == 1) that is also an UIImageView inside the cell's subviews.

```
  let imageView = cell.subviews.first(where: { (temp) -> Bool in
    return temp is UIImageView && temp.tag == 1
  }) as? UIImageView
```

Comment: The error clearly indicate that some view with a tag of `1` is being found. The problem is that the found view is not actually an image view.

Comment: it looks like he's looking for an imageview with tag 1, this is how you find it w/ access to the cell

Comment: @jnblanchard Thank you for your comment! I tried your code but i got this error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: To me it sounds like your cell doesn’t have an image view with a tag. You can add ‘if let’ = imageview.... to prevent this failure ^